# A simple stack calculator in C, need help understanding details

Tags: java, evaluate

```
String hello = "44+"
int result=0, top=-1;
int []stack = new int[hello.length()];
for(int i=0 ; i<hello.length() ; i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        stack[++top]=(int)(c-'0');
    else
    {
        int x=stack[top--]; //pop
        int y=stack[top--]; //pop
        switch(c)
        {
            case '+' : result = x + y;
                break;
            case '-' : result = y - x;
                break;
            case '*' : result = x * y;
                break;
            case '/' : result = y / x;
                break;
            default : result = 0;
        }
        stack[++top]=result; //push
    }
}
result = stack[top--]; //pop
return result;
```

44+ stores 8 -> return result happens and when I print it on the main I get 8 as a output.. which is correct

if I replace this code

```
    stack[++top]=(int)(c-'0');
```

with this one

```
    stack[++top]=(int)(c);
```

the output looks like this = 104.. the second code looks correct to me but it doesn't give me the correct output

My questions are

1. why `c-'0'` is used and not a `c` only ?
2. why `case '-' : result = y - x` is used and not `x - y` ?
3. why `case '/' : result = y / x` is used and not `x / y` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please choose a title describing your problem

Comment: What is `s` on this line: `char c = s.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string (for example "44+") contains a set of characters. Each character in a string is represented by a specific code or value. The string "ABC" is represented by the values 65,66,67 (in decimal). The string "ABC0123456789" is represented by the values 65,66,67,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57 respectively. Therefore, to get the numerical value of the digit characters ('0' to '9') you have to subtract 48 from the character's code.

Regarding your 2nd and 3rd questions: Y is the first number pushed on the stack and X is the second number pushed on the stack. Since the operation is supposed to be between the first and second digits, it should be Y-X and Y/X (it should also be Y+X and Y*X but the order doesn't change the result in this case).

Note that this code won't work well with more than two digits or when the string isn't formatted exactly as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

48 is ASCII of '0'. The characters '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' have the ASCII values 48,49,50, ... , 57

Therefore you can convert the character of a digit to its value by subtracting 48 (which is the same as -'0')

`c - '0'`
is the same as
`c- 48`

Comment: you got my point man, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`c` is character code, which in C are basically integer. So `'0'` is character zero, but it is also number 48 (ASCII code of zero). So, to convert a number character into a C language integer, code like `c - '0'` is often used.

To put it other way, `char c = '0';` and `char c = 48;` are exactly equivalent in C (on computers, which use ASCII encoding).

About order of `x` and `y`, well, `x` was at the top of stack, in other words pushed last, and `y` was 2nd topmost, so which ever order you want to use... If you want to the normal order, that is string `"yx/"` means `y / x`, then you need to write it like that.

Comment: you got my point man, thank you
ur post answered my question completely, and the following post too.. so i'm gonna take the following post as answer since u have 3217 2 21 points and he have only 21 1 , anw.. thank you a lot

Comment: @SaidiTheory :) I never heard anyone chooses an excepted answer in such a way lol. The least you can do is upvote a good answer if you don't accept it. +1 for the socialist comment! (as well as hyde's answer) :)))

Answer (score 1):

This code has bugs, one of them is:
the line:

```
char c = s.charAt(i);
```

should be:

```
char c = hello.charAt(i);
```

This code supposes to take a [`Postfix Expression`](http://www.cs.csi.cuny.edu/~zelikovi/csc326/data/assignment5.htm)  and calculate the total

```
44+  is 4+4
```

in order to calculate the total you should use a stack (which is demonstrated in the code above):

44+ is taken from the stack by two `pop` operations (x=4 and y=4) and the operations is the third pop `+`

Since the numbers are taken as chars from a string it needs to be converted to int, if you'll check the *[ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)* you'll see that '0' is 48 so when you take the char '4' which is 52 and calculate '4'-'0' you get 52-48 which is 4 as requested.

As for the order of the operations, according to `Postfix Expression` the operation should be done in one order:

```
xy+ --> x+y
xy- --> x-y
xy/ --> x/y
xy* --> x*y
```

doing it the other way (`y/x` for example) is a bug.

Comment: nitpick about order of operations: to reflect the question code it should be `yx+` etc, since x is the top of the stack.

Comment: @hyde if I understood you correctly, you are right. The reason I mentioned the order is because of the OP's last two questions.

Comment: u didn't get my question right ?
i saw the s.char it is because the string hello was coded here in stack over flow so users could understand what i mean :D
thank you anyway

Comment: @SaidiTheory I'm not sure I understood your comment: this code will not compile since `s` is undefined.